# Indexing very long number column

Tags: oracle

I have a table with few columns including 2 varchar2(200) columns. In this columns we basically store serial numbers which can be numeric or alpha-numeric. Alpha-numeric values always both serials are same in those 2 columns. However for number serials it is a range like (first column value = 511368000004001226 and second column value = 511368000004001425 with 200 different (Qty)). Maximum length of the serial is 20 digits. I have indexed both the columns.
Now I want to sear a serial in-between the above range. (lets say 511368000004001227). I use following query.

```
SELECT   *
  FROM   Table_Namr d
WHERE   d.FROM_SN <= '511368000004001227'
         AND d.TO_SN >= '511368000004001227'
```

Is it a valid query? Can I use <=> operators for numbers in a varchar column?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. In order to check which one is bigger, you need to first convert the value to a number with `to_number(value)`. But, your query will fail for alpha-numberic values then.

Comment: *"Can I use <=> operators for numbers in a varchar column?"* You can use `<=>` operators for any characters in a string including digits. But they will be evaluated according to their ASCII values not as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is "valid" in the sense, that it works, and will deliver a result. If you are looking from a numeric standpoint, it will not work correctly, as the range operators for VARCHAR columns work the same way, as it would sort an alphanumeric value.

e.g.

```
d.FROM_SN >= '51000'
         AND d.TO_SN <= '52000'
```

This would match for values, as you would expect, like 51001, 51700, but would also deliver unexpected values like 52, or 5100000000000000

If you want numeric selection, you would need to parse it - which of course only works, if every value in these columns is numeric:

```
TO_NUMBER(d.FROM_SN) >= 51000
         AND TO_NUMBER(d.TO_SN) <= 52000
```

Comment: Using TO_NUMBER() is not without costs. It won't use any indexes on those columns unless, they're function-based and indexing TO_NUMBER calls. Also the query will fail if either column contains non-numeric characters. And the OP tells us the serial numbers can be numerical **and** alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use >= and <= operators on Varchar2 columns but it will behave like it is string and comparison between strings will take place.

In this case, 4 will be considered greater than 34 means '4' > '34' but number 4 is less than 34.

It is not a good practice to store a number in Varchar2. You will lose the functionality of Numbers if you store them in varchar2.

You can check the above concept using following:

```
select * from dual where '4' > '34'; -- gives result 'X'
select * from dual where 4 > 34; -- Gives no result
```

You can try to convert the varchar2 column to number using `to_number` if possible in your case.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the similar model in 2 tables and surprisingly varchar2 column with >= and <=  working in one table and other does not.

Comment: In my case I cannot convert it to to_number as it contains alpha numeric serials as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may use alphanumerical comparison provided

1) **your ranges are of the same length** and

2) **all the keys in the range are of the same length**

Example data

```
SERNO                                  
----------------------------------------
101                                      
1011                                     
1012                                     
1013                                     
1014                                     
102                                      
103                                      
104
```

This **doesn't work**

```
select * from tab
where serno >= '101' and serno <= '102';

SERNO                                  
----------------------------------------
101                                      
102                                      
1011                                     
1012                                     
1013                                     
1014
```

But constraining the lentgh of the result provides the **right answer**

```
select * from tab
where serno >= '101' and serno <= '102'
and length(serno) = 3;

SERNO                                  
----------------------------------------
101                                      
102
```

Comment: You gave me a clue here. I modified the query like this and it seems working.  Do you foresee any issue here?

Comment: select * from table_name where From_serial <= '511368000004001227' and to_serial>= '511368000004001227'and length(from_serial) = length('511368000004001227')

Comment: @ChannakaNilendra this will work **if in all rows is valid** `length(from_serial) =  length(to_serial)`.